# Dynamic loading under GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, dynamic-loading

I need to be able to load Haskell modules dynamicaally, and evaluate expressions in the context of dynamically-loaded modules.

[Hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) does it; the problem is, it doesn't work under GHCi, on Windows at least.

```
cygwin-bash> ghci HintTest.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude Main>
Prelude Main> main
[... lots of "Loading package" messages snipped]

GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   _debugLn
whilst processing object file
   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\HASKELL PLATFORM\2013.2.0.0\lib\ghc-prim-0.3.0.0\HSghc-prim-0.3.0.0.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

I get the same error when using GHC modules directly, as shown in [GHC/As a library](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library).

As a compiled program, `HintTest` runs just fine.

Is there anything that can bee done about this?

I don't ever need to run my program stand-alone; always using GHCi is sufficient. It would also be nice if the program could use GHCi itself as the interpreter and not its own copy of GHC. That is, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
do
  context <- loadToGhci "MyModule.hs"
  inContext context "MyModule.myFunction 2 5"
```

and when I return to the REPL, MyModule is magically loaded to it. `context` is meant to be some kind of monad that carries GHCi state.

**Update** The same code works on Linux. Perhaps it's a Windows-specific bug in GHC. Can it be worked around?

**Update 2** 
Here's the full log

```
Prelude Main> main
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package Win32-2.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package syb-0.4.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package random-1.0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.2.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hpc-0.6.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hoopl-3.9.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package haskell-src-1.0.1.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package Cabal-1.16.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package binary-0.5.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package template-haskell ... linking ... done.
Loading package ghc-7.6.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package ghc-mtl-1.0.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package ghc-paths-0.1.0.9 ... linking ... done.
Loading package utf8-string-0.3.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hint-0.3.3.7 ... linking ... done.


GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   _debugLn
whilst processing object file
   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\HASKELL PLATFORM\2013.2.0.0\lib\ghc-prim-0.3.0.0\HSghc-prim-0.3.0.0.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Comment: Both ghci and hint use the ghc api. It's quite possible that using it twice at once results in double-loading some object file on windows. If that's the case, there's not really anything you can do about it unless you want to change the ghc api.

Comment: @Carl I've just checked the same code on Linux and it's working. Perhaps it's just Windows-specific bug?

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding the question correctly, but [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DynamicGhcPrograms) mentions that dynamic libraries aren't completely supported on Windows and has links to a whole host of bugs related to dynamic linking, one of which might be your problem.

Comment: @gereeter I don't think there are dynamic libraries involved. The program loads `.o` files with GHCi's loader.

Comment: @n.m. Can you include the "lots of "Loading package"" output in your post?

Comment: @n.m. does using `:main` instead of `main` in GHCi help?

Comment: @bennofs nope, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to dynamically load the bytecode interpreter and runtime into the bytecode interpreter and runtime. Whether this works will depend on how the underlying C libraries are linked on your system -- which is very platform dependent.

In particular, C symbols will be duplicated unless special care is taken when linking, when you load the various RTS modules the second time, which will lead to linker errors.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, and the reason I'm trying to do it is that the bytecode interpreter and runtime I already have (i.e. GHCi) does not expose its functionality to programs that run under it. Or if it does, I don't know how to use it. OTOH that interpreter has really nice command-line interface that I would like to use too. Do you know of another way to achieve what I want?